# Facebook Graph API like/comment business page recommendation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

(all routes are relative to https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2, GET by default, unless specified)

Steps that work well:

1. I get PAGE's token from here /me/accounts
2. Using pages token go to //ratings?fields=open_graph_story to get the recommendations
3. After getting the recommendation id go to / it works fine
4. //comments - works as expected and returns recommendation commments
5. //likes - works as expected and returns likes

Issues begin when I try to post a comment or like the recommendation

When I try to like a recommendation:

```
POST /<recommendation_id>/likes
```

I receive an error:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID <recommendation_id> does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "AmsWYqiYcS+"
  }
}
```

When I try to post a recommendation:

```
POST /<recommendation_id>/comments {message: 'some'}
```

I receive an error:

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "error_subcode": 2069006,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "User Cannot See This App",
    "error_user_msg": "The user who owns object 2,269,569,259,406 cannot see this app.",
    "fbtrace_id": "BzRCVZFnPk"
  }
}
```

App has following permissions: `publish_pages, manage_pages`
App is an a dev. mode, I'm owning app and a page.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: _“when I try to post a comment or like the recommendation”_ - I can’t find any clear indication in the docs, that this is supposed to be possible in the first place …

Comment: @04FS seems like recommendation is no diffrerent from comment, so if I'm able to like a comment I should be able to like a recommendation...